# what is the correct format of GPS position in OsmDroid?

Tags: android, osmdroid, openstreetmap

I have a GPS device that sends its position via sms in a format like this:

2937.0864,5233.3686,55000

The first digit is latitude, the second digit is longitude and the third digit is alt. When I ask google maps to display the position, it shows an error:

"We could not understand the location 2937.0864,5233.3686"

How can I convert these numbers to valid GPS position? I am writing an app with OsmDroid and I want to use the correct GPS position to display map.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

*2937.0864,5233.3686* are certainly not latitude and longitude, but *29.370864,52.333686* or *29° 37' 08.64", 52° 33' 36.86"* might be the correct position. However, your format still seems weird.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility is that the numbers are from NMEA sentences. See the following answer for the format details.

[NMEA message to Android Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305488/nmea-message-to-android-location)

If so, in your example, the two numbers 2937.0864,5233.3686 mean
29 deg 37.0864 min, and 52 deg 33.3686 min respectively.

To convert to decimal numbers they become 29 + 37.0864/60 = 29.6181066667, and 52 + 33.3686/60 = 52.5561433333